# SQL User in trigger?

Tags: sql, triggers

In my Delete trigger I need to know the username of the person deleting the record.

Is there a SQL function or variable for that?

Comment: Never assume only one record is being deleted.  Hopefully your trigger is set up to work with batch deletes as well as single record ones. Make sure to test it with a multiple record delete.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`suser_sname()` should work.